# Line break with back quotes in a Telegram message – Telegram Bot API

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram

I'm having trouble formatting a message in Telegram.
I need to output each word on a new line.

Example 1:

```js
const text = "word1\nword2\nword3"
```

[Result #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLm17.jpg)

This works, but when I try to output in wildcard quotes (``), it stops working.

Example 2:

```js
const a = "amobus"
const b = "amogus"
const c = "autobus"

const text2 = `
    word1: ${a}
    word2: ${b}
    word3: ${c}
`
```

or

```js
const a = "amobus"
const b = "amogus"
const c = "autobus"

const text2 = `word1: ${a}\nword2: ${b}\nword3: ${c}`
```

or

```js
const a = "amobus"
const b = "amogus"
const c = "autobus"

const text2 = "word1: " + a + "\n" + "word2: " + b + "\n" + "word3: " + c
```

[result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc9Iz.jpg)

This is what it looks like in a real example:

[result 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcUTE.jpg)

But the static text with line breaks is output fine:

[result 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8rC9.jpg)

P.S. In the query I use parse_mode=HTML

```js
const url =`https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}/sendMessagechat_id=${testID}&text=${message}&parse_mode=HTML`
```

Comment: That your second example gets additional whitespace before the words on the 2nd and 3rd line is clear - you introduced that, with the spacing you have in your code.

Comment: Btw., you should really properly URL-encode those values you are inserting into the API URL.

Answer (score 0):

The backticks (`` ` ``) are part of the `parse_mode` `markdown`, so it won't work with `HTML`.

---

Your first example:

```
const text2 = `
    word1: ${a}
    word2: ${b}
    word3: ${c}
`
```

Will include those whitespaces from the beginning, since thats the idea behind the code blocks.

You could append it to your string to prevent that:

```
let text2 = '';
text2 += `word1: ${a}`
...
```

Or start the literal on col 0:

```
const text2 = `
word1: ${a}
word2: ${b}
word3: ${c}
`
```

---

I'd recommend using 3 backticks with parse-Mode `markdown` for better styling
[How to format bot 'send_message' output so it aligns like a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56030395/how-to-format-bot-send-message-output-so-it-aligns-like-a-table)

````
let text = '```';
text += `word1: ${a}`
text += `word2: ${b}`
text += '```';
````